# How can i use 'string.xml' declared variables in build.grade file

Tags: android

I want to use the **string.xml** variables in **build.grade** script.

want to use this app_name variable

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">AppNameConstraintExtra</string>
</resources>
```

in this build.gradle script

```
if(outputFile!=null && outputFile.name.endsWith('.apk'))
                    {
                        def fileName = outputFile.name.replace(
                                "app-release",
                                @string/app_name + defaultConfig.versionName)
                        output.outputFile = new File((String) outputFile.parent, (String) fileName)
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is based on the post from [code4reference.com](http://code4reference.com/2012/08/xml-parsing-gradle-script/). Kudos to Rakesh (who may be or not be @rakesh)

The following code would get your app name. I assume you can take it from there.

```
def stringsXml = (new XmlParser()).parse('app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml')
stringsXml.string.each { string ->
    if (string["@name"] == "app_name") println "Found App: ${string.text()}"
}
```